# PostgreSql replication in docker (different way)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have postgres DB cluster in my docker-compose, at the moment I'm using standard postgres replication mechanism of primary DB and standby replicas with synchronous WAL updates. As I plan to deploy them in one cluster im wondering about another way of doing it, but I'm not sure about side effects so hope you will share with me your expirience.

Instead of builtin postgres mechanism of data replication, I want to create one DB in read/write mode, and then n+1 replicas in read only mode, sharing the same docker volume and exact same data ([its a shared disc solution?](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/different-replication-solutions.html)). I'm wondering if this approach is possible/effective/side-effect-free in postgres.

Thank you for hints!

I tried both, seems to be working as expected on localhost, not sure of side effects.

Comment: In the link you shared: " One significant limitation of this method is that if the shared disk array fails or becomes corrupt..." . There is one side effect for ya.

Comment: @madflow yes, still not sure about this part: "Another issue is that the standby server should never access the shared storage while the primary server is running." as read only replicas would need to connect along with primary server.